# How can I set to a photo I pick from gallery a portrait orientation?

Tags: android

I am trying to get a photo from gallery but it seems that it changes its orientation and I don't know what to do... Here is my code

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
            int orientation = -1;
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);

            try{

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(RecognizeActivity.this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                img_pictureHiragana.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice Android Studio warns about not using `ExifInterface`, but this is how I solved my problem.

```
public static int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, String imagePath)
    {
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }
```